# How can I check based on the url if a file is a audio or video file with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify playlist that has a combo of audio and video media files. I need to be able to launch a video player if it is video or use the html5 audio component if .mp3:

```
        <v-list-item
          v-for="media in media"
          :key="media.title"
          class="mb-2"
        >
          <v-list-item-content
            class="pa-4"
          >
            <v-list-item-title
              class="title"
              v-text="media.title"
            />
          </v-list-item-content>

          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn
              v-else
              icon
              large
              @click="play(media)"
            >
              <v-icon>play_arrow</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-action>
        </v-list-item>
```

In my data the only indicator is the URL structure:

```
 data: () => ({
    media: [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Exploring the culture at GSK',
        url: 'https://youtu.be/RBdgq5VTQmM'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'The meaning of digital innovation: the pharmaphorum podcast',
        url: 'https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/web/vji3n3/Episode_32_Omnipresence_March2021_mixdown8nikx.mp3'
      }]

...
```

Any advice or a point in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: You could check if the URL ends with .mp3 or .mp4 or any other file type specific extensions....although with URLs like YouTube's you won't get very far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-list-item v-for="media in media" :key="media.title" class="mb-2">
      <audio v-if="media.url.includes('mp3')" />
      <video v-else />
    </v-list-item>
  </div>
</template>
```

because the URL are strings i don't think there is a other way